# PostgreSQL find items where daterange is past

Tags: postgresql, date-range

In my PostgreSQL database I have a daterange type where they are all of a format like so:  `[2017-08-01,2018-01-27)`.  I'm trying to figure out a way to identify all elements where the entire range occurs in the past.  Basically I need to do cleanup, so I'm wanting a `DELETE FROM` type statement.

Comment: Is the column a string?  Why the square brace on the left and the parentheses on the right?

Comment: It's not a string, no.  It's of type `daterange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`upper():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html)

```
delete from my_table
where upper(my_column) <= current_date;
```

Comment: So simple!  It won't let me accept your answer for another 9 minutes though.

Comment: The upper bound is exclusive, so shouldn't it be `<= current_date`?